# If every force has an equal and opposite reaction and gravity pulls you down, where is the opposite reaction to gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

If every force has an equal and opposite reaction and gravity pulls you down, where is the opposite reaction to gravity? how come the earth doesn't turn inside-out?

Comment: Related: [Is gravity a force and if so what is its opposite?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/102/)

Comment: Why should the Earth turn inside-out?

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/573427/123208

Answer (score 1):

The answer is *also* gravity!

When the earth pulls you down due to its mass, then you also pull the earth up due to your mass. These two attractive gravitational forces are equal. And they are each other's action/reaction pair from Newton's 3rd law.

Just have a look at the formula for gravitational force:

$$F_g=G\frac{Mm}{r^2}.$$

It involves *both* masses. It is not just a force associated with one mass. The force that you calculate with this formula is the force that *each* object exerts on the other object.

To your last sentence:

> how come the earth doesn't turn inside-out?

I'm sorry, I don't understand this question. Why would the earth turn inside out? If you could elaborate, then I can add an answer to this as well.